# Too many public methods forced by test-driven development

Tags: tdd

A very specific question from a novice to [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development):

I separate my tests and my application into different packages.  Thus, most of my application methods have to be public for tests to access them.  As I progress, it becomes obvious that some methods could become private, but if I make that change, the tests that access them won't work.  Am I missing a step, or doing something wrong, or is this just one downfall of TDD?

Comment: i would think you would want tests in the same "code file unit" as the things being tested. That way they have access to the internal guts.

Comment: As a TDD newb I'm kind of confused still by the dual TDD directives: "don't write a line without testing" and "don't test internals".  If these two are both to be followed it implies that things start off public but become private through refactoring and only through refactoring.  When you do that refactoring you can be sure that you are merely squirrelling already-tested code into a different code configuration.  So far, so puzzling.  But the real head-scratching comes when you also accept the third sacred directive: "never make a method public just for testing purposes".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not a downfall of TDD, but rather an approach to testing that believes you need to test every property and every method. In fact you should not care about private methods when testing because they should only exist to facilitate some public portion of the API.

**Never change something from private to public for testing purposes!**

You should be trying to verify only publicly visible behavior. The rest are implementation details and you specifically want to avoid testing those. TDD is meant to give you a set of tests that will allow you to easily change the implementation details without breaking the tests (changing behavior).

Let’s say I have a type: `MyClass` and I want to test the `DoStuff` method. All I care about is that the `DoStuff` method does something meaningful and returns the expected results. It may call a hundred private methods to get to that point, but I don't care as the consumer of that method.

Comment: But you **do** want a way to test those hundreds of internal methods, no?

Comment: @Ian - If you are doing TDD, then they should already be tested. Their very existence means they were put there in order to make a test pass. However, those methods are an implementation detail that should not be known to the consumer of the class. If I figure out later that I can refactor those 100 methods into 50 methods, I shouldn't have to rewrite my tests. So... yes you test them, but not directly because you only care about the public API. If there is some private method that can't be exercised through the public API, then it is useless and should be removed.

Comment: I am following David Astels 'Practical Guide' - he indicates that you do test those things and then refactor when there is too much intamacy - that would have me change a lot of methods from public to private (not private to public) but then refactor my tests sets to remove the ones that are no longer testing public behavior - does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Theeoretically you are right, but in practice it might be very hard to come up with a way of testing all possible paths inside DoStuff.

Comment: Absolutely. You should refactor your tests just as much as you refactor you underlying code. However, I think you always start with the public API in mind. In my experience this usually doesn't change a lot. In the end what I am saying is this: "If you are creating a private method during your refactoring phase, and it only serves to facilitate a public method, then it should stay private." Don't make it public just because you feel like you need to have every method tested. Think Behavior and not Test... Something I know David Astel is a big proponent of.

Comment: @erikkallen - At that point it would be time to refactor your class and or API in order to make it simpler ;)

Comment: It would be helpful to me if you expanded your answer to give an example how you would solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @erikkallen A tool like DotCover can show you what private methods are not being covered in your unit tests.  And more often than not, if you see a method is not covered, and you ask yourself why it is there, you can come up with a test that will force the code to execute, or you might conclude that the code is not needed.  Part of the benefit of TDD is that your production code becomes lighter.

Answer (score 9):

You don't specify what language you are using, but certainly in most of them you can put the tests in a way that have more privileged access to the class. In Java, for example, the test can be in the same package, with the actual class file being in a different directory so it is separate from production code.

However, when you are doing real TDD, the tests are driving the class design, so if you have a method that exists just to test some subset of functionality, you are probably (not always) doing something wrong, and you should look at techniques like dependency injection and mocking to better guide your design.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem in C# awhile ago - in that language/framework, you want the `InternalsVisibleTo` directive.

Answer (score 7):

This is where the old saying, "TDD is about *design*," frequently comes up.  A class with too many public methods probably has too many responsibilities - and the fact that you are test-driving it only exposes that; it doesn't cause the problem.

When you find yourself in this situation, the best solution is frequently to find some subset of the public methods that can be extracted into a new class ("sprout class"), then give your original class an instance variable of the sprouted class.  The public methods deserve to be public in the new class, but they are now - with respect to the API of the original class - private.  And you now have better adherence to [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), [looser coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling), and [higher cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) - better design.

All because TDD exposed features of your class that would otherwise have slid in under the radar.  **TDD is about** ***design***.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  If only there were an actual book which took you by the hand and showed you how to understand "design smells" of the kind you need to develop sensitivity for for TDD.  Learning from (bitter) experience has its merits, but it ain't half time-consuming.

Comment: Re *"lower cohesion"*: Do you mean *"higher cohesion"* (the opposite)?

Answer (score 1):

At least in Java, it's good practice to have two source trees, one for the code and one for the tests. So you can put your code and your tests in the same package, while they're still in different directories:

```
src/org/my/xy/X.java
test/org/my/xy/TestX.java
```

Then you can make your methods package private.

Comment: I wondered about this... but, following the books (e.g. Growing O-O Software Guided by Tests), it appears best practice to apply a directory hierarchy based on the type of tests, as well (i.e. unit tests, functional tests, end-to-end tests)... which explodes the possibility of using package-private.  I came to the conclusion that you have to drop this as as strategy... (although I am a TDD newb :) )

Comment: @mike rodent: You could still use "unit-test/org/my/xy/UnitTestX.java" and "functional-test/org/my/xy/FunctionalTestX.java". Moreover, it might not be necessary to access the package-private code by _all_ kinds of tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from the class and create harness/mock functions that propagate the call to the internal calls.

For example this is your class:

```
class TestMe {
    function _test(parameter) internal {}
}
```

And then you create this class to test the internal function:

```
class TestMe_Harness is TestMe {
    function test(parameter) public {
        _testMe(parameter);  
    }
}
```

Does obviously only work when the Child can inherit the internal function.